# Highcharts NG stockchart animation effect only on navigator Type: column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, highcharts

I am using highcharts-ng and when i draw column chart with navigator and apply animation on it. only  navigator line animate.

```
 {
  "options": {
    "chart": {
      "backgroundColor": "#eaeaf2",
      "type": "column",
      "zoomType": "xy"
    },
    "navigator": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "plotOptions": {
      "series": {
        "animationLimit": "Infinity",
        "animation": {
          "duration": 9000
        }
      }
    },

  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "useHighStocks": true,
  "series": 
}
]
}
```

[highcharts-ng](http://jsfiddle.net/r88yszk0/487/)

[Jquery highcharts same data](http://jsfiddle.net/gbL3wx65/)

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in highcharts-ng caused by navigator. Reported [here](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/308).
As a workaround you can define global animation in chart property.

```
"chart": {
  "backgroundColor": "#eaeaf2",
  "type": "column",
  "zoomType": "xy",
  "animation": {
      "duration": 9000
    }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/r88yszk0/488/